# How can you determine the create-timestamp for an AWS Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I would like to determine the create-timestamp for an AWS Security Group.

How can this be done?

Comment: The security group itself does not contain this information afaik. I think your best option would be historical CloudTrail API log diving. Going forward, you might choose to maintain this information using your own custom tagging or custom metadata storage. It would be a very useful AWS feature (maintaining creation timestamp and time last modified, imo).

Answer (score 0):

- search Event name "CreateSecurityGroup" in CloudTrail>Event history
- (only if configed previously)search aws Config>Resources for Resources type "AWS EC2 SecurityGroup"
- (only sometimes)see Security Group>Description, it may say "launch-wizard-3 created 2023-08-23T03:45:07.891Z"